# Reading Different Font types with Vision API

Tags: image-processing, google-cloud-platform, ocr, text-extraction, vision-api

I am trying to extract text from such images but Google Vision API does not seem to recognise majority of the text, Can someone suggest a better alternative? [image]

Results from Google OCR
[image]

Comment: Does "lower your extremely optimistic expectations" count?

Comment: could you please show your output? I just tested your image on google cloud vision demo page and i got most of the text detected and recognized correctly.

Comment: @flamelite I added the results, it's good but not enough for me to create a json version of the menu. Could there be some strategy for improving the results

Comment: @DivyeShah what kind of data do you refer by 'menu'?

Comment: @flamelite I meant the a json version of the menu card shown in the picture above

Comment: So you can use the json version information of vision api.

Comment: But it is not accurate enough for me to use that JSON for rendering a menu from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is 593 by 697 pixels, 0.41 MP. The recommended size for character recognition is 1024 x 768. In fact, OCR requires more resolution to detect characters. You may check relevant details on the [Supported Images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) documentation page.